# Alternative to SQL temp tables

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I am using table A and B to create table C after some data manipulation. Table C is my temp table (only have read access to database). In a separate select statement, I am doing my final data prep and table C is being referenced multiple times in my final query.

My problem is the temp tables do not work with create view. And I need to create a view with my final query where I am using temp table C.

Can anyone suggest what can be the alternative to temp tables in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTEs.  In most databases, this would look like:

```
create view D as
    with C as (
          . . .
         )
    select . . .
    from C . . .;
```

Comment: @user12727390 . . . Depends on the database, but they are optimized just like any other SQL code.

Comment: I changed my code with CTE.but it seems the query with subquery was running faster than the one with CTE. any suggestions?

Comment: @user12727390 . . . Ask a new question with more information about your query and a database tag.  This answers the question that you asked here.